# How to get the file back after using "unlink" in R?

Tags: restore, unlink, undelete

I accidentally deleted some of my useful files. The files were deleted and I could not find them in recycle bin. I want to know how can I get it back?
I am using windows 8.1. All the files in My documents deleted using unlink in R. I try to using R-delete to recover, but it only can recover the file deleted from recycle bin not unlink using R.
Thank you.

Comment: I using windows 8.1. All the files in My documents deleted using unlink in R. I try to using R-delete to recover, but it only can recover the file deleted from recycle bin not unlink using R.

Answer (score 2):

Though not being an expert of R, I assume that your file has been unlinked at the file-system level. You can't expect finding it in the recycle bin of your operating system. If it is **very** important, the only real solution is:

- stop immediately doing anything with your computer;
- take the time reading and understanding from *another* computer
- try accessing your hard drive (or whatever) from another mounted filesystem/operating-system (boot with a USB stick for instance)
- use some undelete tool adapted to your filesystem.

You don't tell about your operating system and OS; maybe there will be some tool usable from the mounted filesystem and it may be easier; but anyway, don't use your computer too much before doing it...

Comment: What tool can i use?

Comment: @JKWing I see you are using Windows 8.1; have a look at the list of tools there: http://fasttechbuzz.com/recover-shift-permanently-deleted-files-windows-8-1/